# External url in Django template

Tags: django, templates, stripe-payments

I got receipt url from stripe like:
`"receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1FpzDdEHHOJvKiFZ/ch_1IsB5REHHOJvKiFZGxagDBoQ/rcpt_JVBS4giqfp3YUoHcqzjQAwMHWq",`. I added to template as:
`<div class="status-message">{{ transID.receipt_email }}<br/><a href="{{ transID.receipt_url }}" target="_blank">Find your Receipt here:</a></div>`

When i click on the link i'm redirected to the same page.

view storing fields from stripe:

```
 transID = stripe.PaymentIntent.retrieve(session.payment_intent)

    context = {
        'customer': customer,
        'transID': transID,
    }
```

Is there a way when clicking on the link to redirected to the stripe's receipt_url?

Many thanks.

Comment: can you try printing out `{{ transID.receipt_url }}` to see what it actually returning?

Comment: Thank you for comment. It is returning:
"receipt_url": "https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1FpzDdEHHOJvKiFZ/ch_1IsB5REHHOJvKiFZGxagDBoQ/rcpt_JVBS4giqfp3YUoHcqzjQAwMHWqTC8de" which is the actual receipt for this txn.

Comment: then what the problem? i checked `<a href="https://pay.stripe.com/receipts/acct_1FpzDdEHHOJvKiFZ/ch_1IsB5REHHOJvKiFZGxagDBoQ/rcpt_JVBS4giqfp3YUoHcqzjQAwMHWqTC8de" target="_blank">Find your Receipt here:</a>` it show up and it open up the tab to the url

Comment: on the web page inspec and see if there are any different

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the receipt_url is empty?  That would likely cause the behaviour you're describing.  Maybe try logging it to make sure it's actually present.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! I suppose if it was empty at least i would see empty page or something. But it's actually there, when i click the url in the response from stripe, i see receipt with no problem. But when i try to click the link configured in the template, i see `about:blank` and then redirection to the same page.